# Connecting iPhone to Linux PC via USB cable works only once

Tags: linux, usb, connection, iphone

Connecting an iPhone via USB cable to a Thinkpad laptop running Manjaro Linux works only once. The connection will be confirmed by the phone vibrating three times and the power connection lightning sign appear on its display. On the laptop two mount points appear, one empty and one with a DCIM directory with the phone's pictures in it.

When ejecting both mount points, disconnecting the usb cable and then reconnecting it makes the phone then vibrate just two times, without the lightning sign appearing, and no mount points on the laptop.

Logging off and on does not change anything about this, but rebooting the entire Linux does reset this to working once.

Obviously there is something not correctly detached or some messed up service still running. So the question is: how can I reset this without having to reboot the system?

**edit:**

I did `sudo systemctl restart usbmuxd` as [Notex proposed](https://superuser.com/a/1284087/154140), but still the status log says this, after reconnecting the USB cable:

```
[05:53:24.756][3] Could not get old configuration descriptor for device 1-12: -5
[05:53:25.194][2] Could not get serial number for device 1-12: -6
```

**2. edit:**

After a while of letting it sit it suddenly does work again. So this looks like a valid workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting `usbmuxd` fixes this temporary for me until I reconnect my device again. Hopefully this helps you as well. This might be a bug with `usbmuxd`.

If you are using `systemd` you can restart it like this:

```
systemctl restart usbmuxd
```